# R- Changing the Values of a dataframe depending on a condition

Tags: r

I have numeric values in a dataframe on each columns and I want to change the value of those columns.

For example if a value is less than 100 then it has to be 0 and if it is more than 100 then it has to be 1.

```
data<- read.table(text = "
A B C D
99 101 99 50
90 110 110 151", header = TRUE)
```

then this becomes

```
A B C D
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1
```

Comment: `dat[] <- as.integer(dat > 100)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data<- read.table(text = "
A B C D
99 101 99 50
90 110 110 151", header = TRUE)

for(cl in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[,cl] <- ifelse(data[,cl]>=100, 1, 0)
}
data
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
    data<- read.table(text = "
                 A B C D
              99 101 99 50
              90 110 110 151", header = TRUE)

   dat <- ifelse(data>100 , 1, 0)
   dat
          A B C D
     [1,] 0 1 0 0
     [2,] 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame((data > 100)*1)
#  A B C D
#1 0 1 0 0
#2 0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    mutate_all(funs(+(.>100)))
#  A B C D
#1 0 1 0 0
#2 0 1 1 1
```

Or with `base R`

```
data[]  <- lapply(data, function(x) +(x > 100))
```

---

Other options suggested by @lmo include

```
data[] <- +sapply(data, `>`, 100) 
vapply(data, `>`, 100, FUN.VALUE= numeric(nrow(data)))
```

Comment: Also `dat[] <- +sapply(dat, \`>\`, 100)` or `vapply(dat, \`>\`, 100, FUN.VALUE=rep(0, nrow(dat)))`